# jQuery pricing table calculation

Tags: php, jquery

I have a small e-commerce site, at the moment I have to enter in new product to the database manually, Im in the process of creating a simple admin page where I can use a PHP form to enter the products to the database.

Each product has multiple prices depending on the quantity that a customer purchases, I have created a table using form inputs with the ability to add extra rows using jquery(each product has a varying number of price ranges) for PHP to loop through and add to the prices table.

What I would like to do is be able to enter the minimum quantities for a price and have jquery calculate the maximum quantities based on my minimums.

Heres an example...

```
    <table class='table table-bordered price-table'>
      <thead><th>Min Quantity</th><th>Max Quantity</th><th>Prices</th></thead>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="minquan[]" value="250"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="maxquan[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[] value="250""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="minquan[]" value="500"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="maxquan[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]" value="0.81"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="minquan[]" value="1000"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="maxquan[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]" value="0.77"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

So here, im struggling to figure out a way to have jquery calculate the max quantities and have the last max quantity be something like 9999999.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understood your question, this is i guess what you want.

Also note that i have corrected HTML markup on third `<td>`. Quote was missed there, added `<tbody>` tag to table.

```js
$(function(){
    var min = []; // collect minquan[] here
    var i =0;
    
    $('.price-table input[name="minquan[]"]').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        min.push(value-1);
    });
    
    $('.price-table input[name="maxquan[]"]').each(function(){
        i++;
        if(min[i] !== undefined) $(this).val(min[i]);
        else $(this).val(9999999);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='table table-bordered price-table'>
      <thead><th>Min Quantity</th><th>Max Quantity</th><th>Prices</th></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="minquan[]" value="250"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="maxquan[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]" value="250"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="minquan[]" value="500"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="maxquan[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]" value="0.81"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="minquan[]" value="1000"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="maxquan[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]" value="0.77"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Click `Run code snippet` and let me know if that is what you want.